# Visual Studio Java debugger only supports starting the execution in a named class

Tags: java, visual-studio

I am having problems setting up Java Compiler for Visual Studio and keep getting [this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AblEf.png) I am using Visual Studio 2015 and the latest version of JDK. I downloaded the Java extension [from here.](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bc561769-36ff-4a40-9504-e266e8706f93)

What could be the cause, how do I solve this problem?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you screenshot the project properties debug tab? Also It looks like it is in the pkg subdirectory but doesn't have the corresponding package pkg; line in the code.

Answer (score 5):

This is the answer that nerdyguy64 said in a forum , This ONE work for ME .....
".. I had this same problem but I figured it out.

Do what it says, go into the Debug tab and then go down and click "'PROJECT_NAME_HERE' Properties"

Then click the "Debug" tab on the side and then you will see "Start Class within project:" radio button. Make sure it is clicked and then in the text field along side it type in the class name that has you main method in it.

**Remember, if your main method is within a package you must type the package name then forward slash ("/") and then your class name (with the main method).**

For example: if you start a new console application, you should get a basic hello world console application. Since the basic console hello world application has the main method class in a package (called "pkg"), you have to put in the "Start Class within project" field: "pkg/Program"

Comment: Your last example is worth gold, this was what I was looking for! A simple demonstration in how "to get started" :)

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. If your main method is in Class1.java file.
You go to properties of your project, go to debug tab, and set "Start class within project" as "YourProjectName/Class1".  (Your project name is where the Class1.java is located.)

Answer (score 0):

In vs2015, like hbrtxito says, just set 'pkg/Program' in PropertiesDebug->Start action -> Start class within project